# Screen recording/capture in universal windows app

Tags: youtube-api, win-universal-app, screen-recording

I'm looking for a a way to record my screen in a universal windows app. Afterwards I want to upload the recording to Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

[Office Mix](https://mix.office.com/) is a great tool for this. It's an add-in from Microsoft for Powerpoint. Just start a powerpoint, go to the MIX tab, start a screen recording and you have you video. You can save the video to disc from the presentations and then use other tools to crop, clip and enhance before uploading.

Martin

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your comment. Maybe my question was not completely clear. I'm actually looking for a way to record my own app from code and upload that movie.